# Change customer salutation on success page

Tags: magento2, checkout, template, order-success-page

How can I get customer information on success page (template I think is "success.phtml"). I want to set it to something link "Dear Mr. Hans Mustermann ..."

in **success.phtml** I found this code

```
$block->getOrderId()
```

I have tried `$block->getCustomerName()` or `$block->getCustomerGender()` but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to get ordered customer details.

```
$lid = $block->getOrderId();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($lid);
$billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
echo $billingAddress->getFirstname().' '.$billingAddress->getLastname();
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: My suggestion would be set the customer name in session and get that in success.phtml rather than loading the whole order.

Answer (score 1):

For you are requirement, you need to create a [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for class

```
Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success
```

In this, you need to **pass order object to template file**

And using after method of **prepareBlockData()**, you can do that.

### Plugin

```
<?php

namespace My\Module\Plugin;

class AppendValueAtSuccesspage
{

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory $orderFactory
    ) {
        $this->orderFactory = $orderFactory;

    }

    public function afterPrepareBlockData(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success $subject, $result)
    {
        $orderIncrementId = $result->getOrderId();
        $order = $this->orderFactory->create()->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
        $result->setOrderObject($order);
        return $result;
    }
}
?>
```

### di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success">
        <plugin name="addorderToTemplate" type="My\Module\Plugin\AppendValueAtSuccesspage" />
    </type>
</config>
```

---

`success.phtml`  ***you can get Order object from getOrderObject()***

```
<?php $_order = $block->getOrderObject() ?>
<?php echo __(' %1', $block->escapeHtml($_order->getCustomerFirstname() ? $_order->getCustomerName() : $_order->getBillingAddress()->getName())) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');

$customerName = '';

if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {

   $customerName = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I cannot find a way with Plugin. I will try with Observer Event.

app/code/Vendor/Checkout/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="add_customer_data_order_success"
                  instance="Vendor\Checkout\Observer\AddCustomerDataToOrderSuccess" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/Checkout/Observer/AddCustomerDataToOrderSuccess.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Checkout\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class AddCustomerDataToOrderSuccess implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface
     */
    protected $layout;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
     */
    protected $checkoutSession;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    )
    {
        $this->layout = $layout;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {

        $checkoutBlock = $this->layout->getBlock('checkout.success');
        if($checkoutBlock) {
            $customer = [];
            $order = $this->checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
            $customer['prefix'] = $order->getCustomerPrefix();
            $customer['name'] = $order->getCustomerName();

            $checkoutBlock->setData('customer', $customer);
        }

    }
}
```

We can use boths of `\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session` and `\Magento\Customer\Model\Session` to get customer data.

In the `success.phtml` in your custom theme, we can get the customer data via `$block->getData('customer')`;